# Azure function request Api with cert

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

When I test the api using console program works fine, but when I tried to do using a azure funtion this fail and I have error "Host lock lease acquired by instance ID 000000"

```
X509Certificate2 SenseCert = new X509Certificate2("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\client.pfx");
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };


//Create the HTTP Request and add required headers and content 
string xrfkey = "0123456789abcdef";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https:/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=" + xrfkey);
request.Method = "POST";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.Headers.Add("X-xxxxxxx", xrfkey);
request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
// Add the certificate to the request and provide the user to execute
request.ClientCertificates.Add(SenseCert);
request.Headers.Add("X-xxxxxxxxx", @"UserXXXXXXXXX=internal;UserId=sadasdasdsad");

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd());
```

And my function azure program

```
[FunctionName("CreateShoppingCartItem")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateShoppingCartItems(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "shoppingcartitem")] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("Creating Shopping Cart Item");
        X509Certificate2 SenseCert = new X509Certificate2("client.pfx");
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        string xrfkey = "0123456789abcdef";
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=" + xrfkey);
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-xxxxxxx", xrfkey);
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpWebRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(SenseCert);
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-xxxxxxxxx", @"UserXXXXXXXXX=internal;UserId=sadasdasdsad");
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            log.LogInformation(result);
        }
        return new OkObjectResult("ok");
    }
```

Then I use a cert pfx to authenticate. How do that using azure function.

I have the error when I call post method

[image]

Comment: please post the error you are getting

Comment: Getting "Host lock lease acquired by instance.." does not mean it is an error. When you invoke your http trigger function does it work, have you copied the .pfx file as part of your code deployment? the constructor for X509Certificate2 is being passed a path, is that valid?

Comment: @silent, I update the code, and I have the error "System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: CreateShoppingCartItem. System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates: El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado."

Comment: you might need to post that error in English ;)

Comment: the error "System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: CreateShoppingCartItem. System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates: The system cannot find the specified file."